# How to cache the downloaded packages of the apt-get in travis?

Tags: caching, travis-ci, apt-get

I am using `travis-ci` to test my github repository and I found out that `3` to `10` minutes are spent on downloading `deb` packages. They are only `127 MB` big.

I checked [travis-ci/Caching Dependencies and Directories](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/)
 but there is no support for `apt-get`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this by caching the content in another folder that is accessible for non-root users, and `mv` all `deb` under it into `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. After installation, `cp` them back to that folder.

Note:

I recommand you to make `YOUR_DIR_FOR_DEB_PACKAGES` somewhere under `~`.

```
# .travis.yml

sudo: required

cache:
  - directories:
    - $YOUR_DIR_FOR_DEB_PACKAGES # This must be accessible for non-root users

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      # Whatever source you need

# Download the dependencies if it is not cached
# All the "echo" and "ls" in "before_script" can be remove since they are only used for debugging.
before_script:
  - echo "Print content of $YOUR_DIR_FOR_DEB_PACKAGES"
  - ls $YOUR_DIR_FOR_DEB_PACKAGES
  - echo "Check whether apt-get has no cache"
  - ls /var/cache/apt/archives
  -
  - echo "Start loading cache"
  - |
    exist() {
        [ -e "$1" ]
    }
  - |
    if exist ~/$YOUR_DIR_FOR_DEB_PACKAGES/*.deb
    then
        sudo mv ~/$YOUR_DIR_FOR_DEB_PACKAGES/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
        ls /var/cache/apt/archives
    fi
  -
  - echo "Start to install software"
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests $THE_PACKAGES_REQUIRED
  -
  - echo "Start updating the cache"
  - cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*deb ~/$YOUR_DIR_FOR_DEB_PACKAGES/

script:
  - # Do whatever you want here.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like this is not a recommended practice.
According to [official documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching)

> Large files that are quick to install but slow to download do not
>   benefit from caching, as they take as long to download from the cache
>   as from the original source:
>
> - Debian packages